# 'Cannot set property “innerHTML” of undefined' - but it is defined

Tags: javascript, html

Curious problem, when using '.innerHTML' on a JS element object I am seeing the error 'Cannot set property “innerHTML” of undefined', yet it isn't undefined as I can print it to console with console.log(myElement) on the line before. This error appears when using Chrome and Firefox.

Furthermore, 'myElement.innerHTML("text")' is working, even with this error, so my code is working (functionally), but I wonder if it could create some unforeseen issues, or if this is just a bug.

The code that creates the issue/bug is:

```
var errorList = event.target.getElementsByClassName("errorList")[0];
  console.log(errorList);    // successfully displays my intended element
  errorList.innerHTML = "";  // successfully clears the <ul class='errorList'>
```

Comment: Please add code that replicates the issue. The element you're trying to set the `innerHTML` of is `undefined` at the time. Maybe it's a typo, maybe it hasn't loaded yet, etc. But your question leaves us with nothing but "possibles" and guesses. We can help you more if you help us more :)

Comment: That code alone will not throw any errors unless there is no element with class `errorList`, so yeah create a jsFiddle reproducing the problem.

Comment: html of element?

Comment: where is the code that produces the problem?

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, the question's a bit confusing. You say "This is the code that creates the bug", but then the comments on that code say that it does everything "successfully"...?

Comment: @MTL-VRN yeh thats it, cheers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you use events, switch to `document` while invoking `getElementClassByName`.
`event.target` is not always what you believe, try to log it to catch the issue.

**Working example**

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("errorList")[0].addEventListener("click",
function(event){
var errorList = document.getElementsByClassName("errorList")[0];
  console.log(errorList);    // successfully displays my intended element
  errorList.innerHTML = "";  })
```

```html
<ul class="errorList">
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

**Event example** (return undefined on log)

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("errorList")[0].addEventListener("click",
function(event){
var errorList = event.getElementsByClassName("errorList")[0];
  console.log(errorList);    // successfully displays my intended element
  errorList.innerHTML = "";  })
```

```html
<ul class="errorList">
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code may be running multiple times, perhaps at startup or page load.  If this happens, and at one of the times that it runs, the "errorList" element does not exist, the error could be thrown at that time - even if it successfully runs later.

To check for this, I recommend adding something like

```
console.log("TEST!");
```

before the

```
var errorList = event.target.getElementsByClassName("errorList")[0];
```

If the "TEST!" shows up multiple times in the console, you'll know it's running more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add load event in order to get the element when DOM is ready.

```js
function init(){
 var el = document.getElementById("btn");
 el.addEventListener('click',function(){ alert("Button clicked"); });
}


addEventListener('load',init);
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```